# Gnome 43. missing Minimize and full screen icons not working

Tags: linux, gnome, theme, bugs

I have a problem since i upgraded my gnome to 42. i thought it will get fixed on 43 but it still have the problem

the problem is: all Gnome application have no minimize and full-screen button. but there is a circle instead of them. but when i hover it. it change for the actual icon.

and it is the same for (

- nautilus(file manager)
- Setting
- Extensions
- Console
  Meaning all the Native gnome applications they are all like this

[image]

### i dont know how to be able to fix this. as i dont know GTK so i dont understand the code

another proplem is i am unable to change nautilus theme from gnome 42. i dont know if it is possible to get fixed or they changed it to a stable UI which is pretty bad

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a glitch with either your icon theme or your GTK theme, which needs to be updated by the respective devs to work with Gnome 43. Switch to default themes and things should work normally.